# Doxygen -- How to link to a C++ file-scope global variable

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some code that looks like this:

### MyStruct.h

```
struct MyStruct
{
    // ...

    /**
      * \brief Initializes \link MYSTRUCT \endlink.
      */
    static void init();
};

/**
 * \var MYSTRUCT
 * \brief You must call MyStruct::init() before using this variable.
 */
extern MyStruct const * MYSTRUCT;
```

### Question

I would like to have the Doxygen documentation on `MyStruct::init` link to the Doxygen documentation on `MYSTRUCT`. However, Doxygen can't resolve the link as I provide it. What do I need to do to make the link work?

NOTE: Doxygen v 1.8.4 on Windows 7

Comment: Did you try `\link ::MYSTRUCT \endlink`? And wasn't there s.th. like `\ref` ?

Comment: It's actually in a namespace, which I deleted for simplicity. So I did try \link ns::MYSTRUCT \endlink.

Comment: No! I would have said if it did :). In the end none of the combinations I tried worked, so I ended up moving `MYSTRUCT` within the scope of `MyStruct` (as a static member variable). It's frustrating that the documentation system dictated the design, but I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: Did you check one of these options [Links to other members](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/autolink.html#linkother)? Sorry `\ref` is the wrong path here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the corrected example that should work. Note that I added a comment block with \file (and removed the redundant \var)

```
/** \file */

/** My struct documentation */
struct MyStruct
{
    // ...

    /**
     * \brief Initializes \link MYSTRUCT \endlink.
     */
    static void init();
};

/**
 * \brief You must call MyStruct::init() before using this variable.
 */
extern MyStruct const * MYSTRUCT;
```

If you don't want a page with global data, but want MYSTRUCT to appear as part of MyStruct's documentation you can use \relates like so:

```
/** My struct documentation */
struct MyStruct
{
  // ...

  /**
   * \brief Initializes \link MYSTRUCT \endlink.
   */
  static void init();
};

/**
 * \brief You must call MyStruct::init() before using this variable.
 * \relates MyStruct
 */
extern MyStruct const * MYSTRUCT;
```

and you can use `#MYSTRUCT` as a short-hand notation for `\link MYSTRUCT \endlink`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I used your first example and it works great!